# Getting a value from XML File (no unique ID for node)

Tags: xml, powershell

I have a following XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Objects>
    <Object Type="System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject">
        <Property Type="System.String" Name="FolderName">Mozilla_Firefox</Property>
        <Property Type="System.Int32" Name="Export">6</Property>
    </Object>
    <Object Type="System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject">
        <Property Type="" Name="ExportListing"/>
        <Property Type="System.String" Name="FolderName">Notepad</Property>
        <Property Type="System.Int32" Name="ExportCountZips">1</Property>
    </Object>
</Objects>
```

I want to get a value of property 'Export' for particular 'FolderName'.
Here is how I obtain a XML Line with Notepad:

```bsh
$t = $xml.Objects.Object.Property |
     ? { $_.Name -eq 'FolderName'} |
     Where '#text' -eq 'Notepad'
```

How to get a proper 'ExportCountZips' with a value of 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [XPath expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx):

```
$name  = 'Notepad'
$xpath = "//Object[Property[@Name='FolderName']/text()='$name']/Property[@Name='ExportCountZips']"
$xml.SelectSingleNode($xpath) | Select-Object -Expand '#text'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ExportCountZips = ($xml.objects.object.property | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "ExportCountZips"})."#text"
```